# Process.RedirectStandardOutput does not work

Tags: c#, process, output

I have a problem redirecting standard output of an application. It seems like this is some kind of bug in .NET.

I'm running [Live555ProxyServer](http://www.live555.com/) but I don't get any output even when console which starts does have a written output. This code works with any other console application but not with this one.

```
void StartProcess()
{
    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"live555ProxyServer.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-R";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;

    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
}

void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```

The source code of that application can be found [here](https://github.com/doghell/live555/blob/master/proxyServer/live555ProxyServer.cpp)

Comment: Have you checked that the process actually starts? process.Start() returns a boolean which should be true if the process started.

Comment: Yes it does start you can see that process and you can also see that it does have an output written in the console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is because all output goes to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, see [source code](https://github.com/doghell/live555/blob/master/BasicUsageEnvironment/BasicUsageEnvironment.cpp)

You should add a handler for [`Process.ErrorDataReceived`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and call [`Process.BeginErrorReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginerrorreadline(v=vs.110).aspx) and things will start going smoothly.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out. The problem now is that ErrorDataRecieved is fired only after I close appliacation. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Probably because newlines are missing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin You can change the code and add `fprintf(stderr, "\n");` or `fflush(stderr);` after each `fprintf` call.

Comment: Strange thing in that answer is that they say `stderr` is unbuffered which seems not to be the case here.