# C# Prevent a started app from writing in the console

Tags: c#, .net-core, console

I have an app which starts another app. This other app prints a few lines into the Console but noone needs this output and it prints it's output betwenn my own. How can I prevent this other app from printing it's stuff into my console?
I tried to run with `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecutive` both on `true` and `false`, also tried to change the console output into a MemoryStream before starting but since I need the Console i had to change the output back and it looks like the other app got their input changed back too.

```
Process serverprocess = new Process();
serverprocess.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetFileName(serverpath);
serverprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = launch;
serverprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
serverprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
serverprocess.Start();
```

Comment: how did you redirect the child process stdout to a memorystream? show at least that part of the code. redirection (something like `>nul`) could also work.

Comment: Added.. by you :)

Comment: would this apply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642517/1132334
(setting `RedirectStandardOutput` to true, and just not attaching any handler to `OutputDataReceived`)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly but I added the redirection and haven'T added anything to OutputDataRecieved but it still shows up in my console :( (Changed the post to current code)

Comment: maybe the child process writes to stderr and not to stdout. redirect the error output as well, there is a separate property for that. related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29967590/1132334

Comment: It was the error stream... I hate ARK sometimes.
If you post this as an answer I can mark it as correct answer :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Process.RedirectStandardOutput does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967590/process-redirectstandardoutput-does-not-work)

Comment: It was the error stream, not the output. Now my console is free of ARKs output :)
You already told the right thing with the stderr :)
Make an answer with this information and I can mark it as solution ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code ensure that you are *re-directing* both `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` that way everything that the "ThirdPartyApp" writes will be captured in either of these *streams*.

I have written a small Helper Class that helps with this

You can use like

```
//Launching excel.exe with /safe as arg
var excelExample1 = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE"" /safe";

LaunchCMD.Invoke(excelExample1);

//To get its output, if any
var getOutput = LaunchCMD.Output;
```

**LaunchCMD Helper Class**

```
class LaunchCMD
{


    public static string Output
    {
        get; set;
    } = "";




    public static void Invoke(string command, bool waitTillExit = false, bool closeOutputWindow = false)
    {

        ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
        Process Process = new Process();


        ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C " + command);


        ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        Process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);


        Process.ErrorDataReceived += ConsoleDataReceived;
        Process.OutputDataReceived += ConsoleDataReceived;


        Process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        Process.BeginErrorReadLine();




        if (waitTillExit == true)
        {


            Process.WaitForExit();
        }
        if (closeOutputWindow == true)
        {
            Process.CloseMainWindow();
        }


        Process.Close();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Output.ToString();


    }


    private static void ConsoleDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            Output = Output + e.Data;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I had to redirect the streams but I don't need any attached handler for this streams, I just forgot that the ARK server may also use stderr instead of stdout so I only redirected stdout into nothing :/